# why do i get empty lists returned from web scraping?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

i am trying to get the weather from a website and collect this data. but some requests return empty lists or different information then expected. why does this happen and what is the correct format and method to getting the right xpath and information from a website.

i have tried using multiple websites but cannot consistantly get results.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

site1data = requests.get('http://m.bom.gov.au/vic/melbourne/', verify = 
False)
tree = html.fromstring(site1data.content)

humidity = tree.xpath('//div[@class="humidity"]/text()')

print(humidity)
```

the expected result was something like:
67%
but i got:
['\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t']

Comment: there are inner tags in it `//div[@class="humidity"]/p/text()`. To get all text nodes use : `//div[@class="humidity"]/*/text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the text data you are looking for is presented inside a `<p>` tag, not inside the `<div>` itself:

```
<div class="humidity">
    <h3>Humidity</h3>
    <img class="humidity" src="/assets/images/ui/humidity.svg" />
    <p>65%</p>
</div>
```

This xpath should solve your immediate problem:

```
humidity = tree.xpath('//div[@class="humidity"]/p/text()')
```

Comment: so does this mean i have to include tags at the end of path to be taken to a more specific point in the website?

Comment: @BOBTHEBUILDER Generaly, yes. You use XPath to navigate the "bones" of the document - the DOM. It's one of the tools that allows for precision scraping. W3C has a [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) for xpath. But have a look at QHarr's answer as well. APIs are quite common nowadays and it's useful to be familiar with their use.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the site they offer a beta site which is API fed so you can get all the info from that endpoint as json

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.weather.bom.gov.au/v1/locations/r1r0fs/observations').json()
print(r)
```

[image]